# Custom migration: Getting error SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: migrations

I'm quite new to Drupal and tried my first Migration from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8. I didn't want to migrate the entire page but only some nodes.
So i got a tutorial and wrote a custom migration module (with dependencies of Migrate Plus and Migrate Drupal) with the following files in it:

- one migration-group.yml
- two .yml with the field mapping definitions for my entities
- an .info.yml for my module

When I do a migration-status with drush, i can see my two migration entities. But when I try to migrate-import one of them, I get the following error:
 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found
But actually the table is right there in the db.

I executed the following drush commands:

```
vendor/bin/drush ms --uri=mydrupal8-site.test
```

The result is:[image: migration_id]
So everything's fine.

Then i run the command:

```
vendor/bin/drush migrate:import external_page_01 --uri=mydrupal8-site.test
```

...and i get the error.
I have to use the --uri-param because i have a multisite-installation.
I have put the legacy-Database connection into my settings.php-file, like so:

```
    'database' => 'd8',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
);
$databases['legacy']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'd6',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

I read a post according to this topic which unfortunately refers to a D6 to D7 migration, so those anwers don't work for me.

Does anybody know how to solve this for D8?

Thanks and best regards
Rebekka

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if there is enough information here. It may help to include some more details about the arguments for the drush commands you ran. It's possible that maybe migrate-import doesn't know how to connect to the source database for your migration.

Comment: Hello mradcliffe, thx for your answer. I have the command "drush migrate:import external_page_01 --uri=mydrupal8-site.test". The parameter --uri is necessary cause i have a multisite-drupal running and otherwise the module cant be found.